# Saving Symbology from MXD as Image File

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-online

I was given an .mxd that contained icons I need to save and reuse in a webmap.

Is there any way to save these icons as .png or .jpegs instead of .style files?

Comment: What type of markers are the symbols (character/picture/simple)?

Comment: They are pictures

Answer (score 1):

(Moved to answers for better formatting control)

If they are picture markers then there will already be an image file for each marker.  The path for the image will be shown on the 'Symbol Property Editor' dialogue box - you'll just have to find the image for each symbol in the legend.

[image]

If you're symbols are characters or simple markers it's a whole different issue.

Comment: sadly there is no path for the picture

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get in contact with the author of the .mxd and got the symbols as .png files, problem solved.